# Which is the best algorithm to find sum of all subarray?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, c++14

for example if

```
a[3]={1,2,3}
```

> ```
>  1,2,3,1+2,2+3,1+2+3
> ```
>
> so my program should print
>   1
>   2
>   3
>   3
>   5
>   8

I know there exits a formula for calculating the total sum.
But what i want is efficient method to calculate individual sums.

A seg tree advisable?

Comment: By an individual sum do you mean a sum of a subarray of the array?

Comment: It's just two loops from `0 <= startIndex < 3` and `1 <= length <= 3 - startIndex`, isn't it?

Comment: Its just an example :p

Comment: There are tens of similar questions during last week. Use search.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that by subarray you mean what some authors conventionally call subarray being a contiguous slice of an array, you are looking for [Kadane's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem#Kadane.27s_algorithm).

It works by incrementally finding the biggest subarray. At any given point of the search, the maximum subarray on that index is either the empty array (sum == zero) or consists of one more element than the maximum subarray that ended at the previous position. You keep track of what is the best you've ever found so you can compare subarrays with the best so far and return the actual best solution.

It may also be extended to multiple dimensions.

Comment: @venkatesanravi So there you have it. I will add why it works with my own words, it may help you. It is a very understandable algorithm when compared to some academic monsters out there.

Comment: But Kadane's algo can be used only to get the maximum subarray only right?Or it can be used to get sum of all subarrays too?

Comment: It does not sum all subarrays. That can be done in O(n) time by accumulating the products of each element by how many subarrays it is part of. The number of how many subarrays an element a_i is part of is given by the product of left endpoints and right endpoints, this is `i * (n - i + 1)` where `i` is the 1-indexed index of the element.

Comment: If u can explain it for clearly by taking an example i will be greatly thankful to you! Take the array i have asked in the ques

Comment: ^^ I was waiting for that :((

Comment: @venkatesanravi `a[3]={1,2,3}`. n = 3 (number of elements). For the first element, we have i = 1 and e = 1. e is the value of the element. So it adds (i * (n - i + 1) * e) = (1 * (3 - 1 + 1) * 1) = 3 to the sum. For the second element we have i = 2 and e = 2. So it adds (i * (n - i + 1) * e) = (2 * (3 - 2 + 1) * 2) = 8 to the sum. So far we have 11. Lastly, we get i = 3, e = 3, which adds (i * (n - i + 1) * e) = (3 * (3 - 3 + 1) * 3) = 9 to the sum, totalling 20. You can check it: 1 + 2 + 3 + (1 + 2) + (2 + 3) + (1 + 2 + 3) = 6 + 3 + 5 + 6 = 20.